# Blank OpenCart view

Tags: opencart

Controller:

```
 <?php
    class ControllerSalesnewCalendar extends Controller{
        public function index(){
            $this->template = 'sales/newCalendar.tpl';
            $this->response->setoutput($this->render());
      }
    }
    ?>
```

View:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(1);
   echo $header; 
?>
<iframe src="http://calendar.ubpbackyard.com/" height="1000" width="2000" 
scrolling="no"></iframe>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

The view is blank. OpenCart Gurus, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If your are working on opencart 2.3, then try this

**Controller**

```
class ControllerSalesnewCalendar extends Controller{
 public function index(){
  $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
  $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

  $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('sales/newCalendar', $data));
 }
```

}

**View**

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<iframe src="http://calendar.ubpbackyard.com/" height="1000" width="2000" 
scrolling="no"></iframe>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: It is OpenCart 1.4.9

Comment: If it is solved then please share your code also here so that people can get help from your post.

Comment: Will work same on OC 1.4.9?